# QPainterPath percentage/t value for Element

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QPainterPath that has two Elements, both of which are cubic Bezier curves, like this:

If I want to find a particular point along the path, I can use the `pointAtPercent` method.  The documentation states that

> When curves are present the percentage argument is mapped to the t parameter of the Bezier equations.

[image]

When I get the percentage, it's from 0 to 1 along the length of the *entire* path.  That middle control point, for example, is at t = 0.46, when actually it's the end of the left Element (t = 1.0) and the start of the next (t = 0).  So in my image if I get the percentage at the green circle, it'll be around 0.75.  What I'd *like* is to get something like 0.5 for the green circle, i.e. the percentage of just the second Bezier.

So my question is, is there a way in Qt to determine the percentage value of a given Element instead of relative to the entire path length?  In my example I happen to know the percentage value for the middle control point, but in general I won't know it, so I can't just scale the percentages or assume even distribution.

I'm using PyQt4 (Qt 4.8) if that matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` scales along the total `length()`, but you can also know the length of individual segments, and thus adjust `t` accordingly. The path's *element* is a rather specific term: there are 3 elements per each `cubicTo`, assuming no intervening position changes. An arbitrary path like yours with consist of a `MoveToElement`, `CurveToElement`, two `CurveToDataElement`s, another `CurveToElement`, another two `CurveToDataElement`s. You have to iterate the elements and extract the length of the first cubic, to adjust the `t`.

A function extracting the first cubic, determining its length, and then using that to compute `t2` from `t` would look similar to (untested):

```
def t2(path, t):
   if path.elementCount() != 7:
      raise ValueError('invalid path element count')
   path1 = QPainterPath()
   path1.moveTo(path.elementAt(0))
   path1.cubicTo(path.elementAt(2), path.elementAt(3), path.elementAt(1))
   l = path.length()
   l1 = path1.length()
   l2 = l - l1
   t2 =  (t*l - l1)/l2
   return t2
```

Comment: Thank you!  I guess I hadn't thought of reconstructing the path out of the elements to find the length.  I found that for a longer path (i.e. n curves instead of 2), if I keep adding the length to l1 it still holds.  The only case that doesn't work with this generality is the first section, because l2 needs to be the length of the first curve instead of l - l1 (because l1 is effectively 0 so l2 == l, and therefore t2 == t, which isn't accurate).  But with that special case I now have what I want!  Thanks again!